# Xamarin - Can't start debugging "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I try to create a Xamarin app. When I try to start debugging i have this error : "The system cannot find the file specified."

I searched on internet and tried multiples solutions that didn't worked (repair VS, check if Mono debugging is enable...)

I don't know how to make it work.

Here is the error output : 
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzbfI.png)

And my extension :
[extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U85fj.png)

I'm using VS 2019

Comment: First of all, please close the VS , open your project folder, delete the all of the `bin` and `obj` folders(xxxxx, xxx.Droid, xxxx.IOS) in your project, then open your project again, rebuild it. Did you try to create a new project? If this issue is disappear?

Comment: Aside from the above suggestion, also make sure your Xamarin packages have been updated

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I deleted every bin and obj folder and tried to create a new project but the issue sill appear..

Comment: Please  remove the none english characters from your path it will allow you to rebuild and debug the application on the device. you can refer to this thread.https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/745431/error-failed-to-open-directory-the-system-cannot-f.html

Comment: Is there any update for this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My problem was that my path contained a non-english caracter (C:/Users/Clément). 
I had to rename my user folder and it worked.

Comment: As noted above, the error might appear if the project's path contains non-English characters. But if in your case it's the user folder, you don't have to rename this folder (which might make problems in other softwares).
Just create a new folder at `C:\Users`, copy the project directory into it, and re-open the solution file on its updated location.
For example:
`C:\Users\vsprojs\myproject`

Answer (score 0):

Generally this problem comes due to Mono Debugging disabled, please check and confirm it is enable or not then try.

=> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64    *for 64 bit system*

=> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib        *for 32 bit system*

Property manager-> Linker-> General->Additional library Directories