# .Net MAUI Debugging on Android Device: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, maui

When I want to debug my newly created .Net MAUI Blazor application on my Android Emulator I get this error
[Error(Translation: The system cannot find the file specified.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToFjp.png)
The device is running. I have changed the storage location of the devices to

> D:\Android Emulator\

There is a similar question with the same problem
[Xamarin - Can't start debugging "The system cannot find the file specified."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59563352/xamarin-cant-start-debugging-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)
but in my path there are no non english characters so this wont save my problem

Comment: Does this happen with a newly made project (not your code)? If so, maybe it doesn't like blank character in path? Otherwise, try deleting Visual Studio, reinstall.

Comment: I have reinstalled Visual Studio and the emulator is now installed in "D:\Android", but the same error still appears. Also debugging on the windows machine works.

Comment: Something must be strange. Check folder and file properties / access? I would let vs create emulator in whatever its default location is. If that works, then report at `github maui issue` a problem with non-standard location.

Comment: I  have installed the emulator in the standard location and now it works.